# How to fix error setup cluster neo4j 5.2?

Tags: neo4j

Has anyone ever had the following error, when installing neo4j cluster with 3 nodes, I followed the indication in the site https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup/deploy/: Caused by: com.neo4j.causalclustering.seeding.FailedValidationException: The seed validation failed with response [RemoteSeedValidationResponse{status=FAILURE, remote=XXXX:6000

I follower the indication in the site https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup/deploy/

Comment: Had the same issue, not sure about the solution. Offering a bounty of 500 for someone to answer.

Comment: @JasperBlues: [This is a link](https://discord.com/channels/787399249741479977/1073766053215219772/1075249722413043883) to your related question on discord. An answer _might_ appear there.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is a tricky subject, but neo4j is using several ports for clustering. Port 6000, specifically, is for clustering transactions and in this case, it's failing the seed validation process. Now I can see a couple of potential reasons for this.

- The network's control plane doesn't allow you to establish a connection. (check the reachability of ports)
- Your cluster configuration is not compatible with the environment you are running (check what interface the server listens to and that the cluster DNS resolves your addresses, and check your cluster is not using a loopback address as the interface, setting it to 0.0.0.0 would listen on all interfaces)
- or you are trying to start a cluster with pre-existing data that is out of sync (term). (Drain your nodes, remove all instances (and volumes) and if you can, terminate the namespace and try again)
- Your scheduler does not have enough cluster resources to start all cluster servers with the given constraint, failing the minimum required amount of nodes available to run clustering. (There should not be more than one db instance per node). Scale-out you cluster or check you settings for Taints, Tolerances or Topology configuration

Hope this helps you troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: yeah clustering is a tricky topic. Don't want to take over original poster's question, but for me, I usually recommend to clients to start with a single instance, then resolve clustering in collaboration with Neo4j. However there's strong interest in getting set up straight away in this case. To that end: First two points I have checked prior to posting on Discord. Third is not applicable for me I think? (It is a fresh env w/ only system DB to seed). Final one . . can you point me at any more info on this?

Comment: I think easiest is you use OpenLens to inspect your deployment, but you can also run "kubectl describe pod somepod" and see if the scheduler has reported anything in the status.

Comment: Oh you're talking k8s cluster? The cluster where I faced above error is running on GCP instances provisioned via terraform.